# find nearest point and show properties from nearest point into user created marker in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

[Example](https://bl.ocks.org/rgdonohue/0598de175f591803fa97d65d8330f40d) I'm trying to find the nearest markers on a map of a specific location with Leaflet, want to show popup info on user created marker which is find nearest point, popup info should be include with nearest point properties from the geojson data layer.
example maker.bindpopup(feature.properties.name).addTo(map)

```
(function() {
   
    var geojosn1= 'url1';
    var geojsonn2= 'url2';
    
    var stations,
        $body = $('body'),
        $locate = $('#locate'),
        $findNearest = $('#find-nearest'),
        $status = $('#status');
    
    $.getJSON(geojosn1, function(data) {
  
        //$('#loader').fadeOut();
        $body.addClass('loaded');
        
        stations = L.geoJson(data, {
            
            pointToLayer : function(feature, latlng) {
               return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                   stroke : false,
                   fillColor : 'orange',
                   fillOpacity : 1,
                   radius: 2
               });
            }
        }).addTo(map); 
        

        $locate.fadeIn().on('click', function(e) {
            
            $status.html('finding your location');
            
            if (!navigator.geolocation){
                alert("<p>Sorry, your browser does not support Geolocation</p>");
                return;
            }
            
            $body.removeClass('loaded');
              
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
            
           $locate.fadeOut();
            
        });   
    });

    function success(position) {
        
        $body.addClass('loaded');
        
        var currentPos = [position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude];
        
        map.setView(currentPos, zoomLevel);

        var myLocation = L.marker(currentPos)
                            .addTo(map)
                            .bindTooltip("you are here")
                            .openTooltip();
        
            
        $findNearest.fadeIn()
            .on('click', function(e) {
                
                $findNearest.fadeOut();
                
                $status.html('finding your nearest locations')
            
                queryFeatures(currentPos, 5);
            
                myLocation.unbindTooltip();
            
                
        });

    };

   
    function queryFeatures(currentPos, numResults) {
        
        var distances = [];
        
        stations.eachLayer(function(l) {
            
            var distance = L.latLng(currentPos).distanceTo(l.getLatLng())/1000;
            
            distances.push(distance);

        });
        
        distances.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
        
        var stationsLayer = L.featureGroup();
            

        stations.eachLayer(function(l) {
            
            var distance = L.latLng(currentPos).distanceTo(l.getLatLng())/1000;
            
            if(distance < distances[numResults]) {
                
                l.bindTooltip(distance.toLocaleString() + ' km from current location.');
                
                L.polyline([currentPos, l.getLatLng()], {
                    color : 'orange',
                    weight : 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    dashArray : "5, 10"
                }).addTo(stationsLayer);
                
            }
        });
        
        map.flyToBounds(stationsLayer.getBounds(), {duration : 3, easeLinearity: .1 });
        
        map.on('zoomend', function() {
          
            map.addLayer(stationsLayer);
        })
      
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function queryFeatures(currentPos, numResults) {
    var stationsLayer = L.featureGroup();
    
    var result = {
        layer: null,
        dis: 0,
        marker: null
    };
    
    stations.eachLayer(function(l) {
        var distance = L.latLng(currentPos).distanceTo(l.getLatLng())/1000;
        if(result.layer == null || distance < result.dis) {
            var line = L.polyline([currentPos, l.getLatLng()], {
                color : 'orange',
                weight : 2,
                opacity: 1,
                dashArray : "5, 10"
            });
            
            result = {
                layer: line,
                dis: distance,
                marker: l
            };
        }
    });
    
    result.marker.bindTooltip(result.dis.toLocaleString() + ' km from current location.');
    result.layer.addTo(stationsLayer);
    
    map.flyToBounds(stationsLayer.getBounds(), {duration : 3, easeLinearity: .1 });
    
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
        map.addLayer(stationsLayer);
    });
}
```

Comment: and also marker should be show properties of point data

Comment: you can achive this with: `result.marker.feature.properties`

Comment: What If  I have two geojson layers, I want to show properties of geojson polygon layer on marker.

Comment: You have to find the polygon and then read it out with`polygon.feature.properties` and then you can open a popup with the data. Please accept the answer if it has worked for (with the first question)

Comment: popup should only one for two layers

Comment: create a new question and it would be the best with a working fiddle, because I don't understand it